# Compare Dates (stored as string) in android sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

How to compare dates which stored as String in Sqlite Database and fetch data...?

I am storing date in a format `19-03-2014 14:23:43`
I have tried `BETWEEN` and also `>=` and `<=` but none of them is working. And I want to compare only Date and not Time. So I am passing value as `20-03-2014`, If time is necessary to pass then I don't have any problem to pass `00:00:00`

Comment: Why do you store them as strings?

Comment: convert date and time to milliseconds and compare it.

Comment: You can also achieve this by just changing DataType of date from `String` to `DATETIME`.

Comment: @BlackTiger, I have changed DataType from String to DATETIME, now I am passing only date as 19-03-2014 and 20-03-2014 so should I use BETWEEN or >= and <=. And Do I need to convert 19-03-2014 to DATETIME ?

Comment: @ianhanniballake, I was new to sqlite and I want to stored DATETIME in specific format so I used it as String.

Comment: No, just change datatype no need to change in code i hope you will get desire result ,..

Comment: @BlackTiger, I have changed DataType to DATETIME and now, I am firing query like : Select * from tblUserResponse Where ResponseDate >= '31-03-2014' AND ResponseDate <= '01-04-2014' but I am not getting result. Data are there on these dates.

Comment: @BlackTiger, If I am using datetime format as yyyy-MM-dd then It is working fine. Not working in dd-MM-yyyy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String comparisons use the lexicographical ordering of characters.

To be able to compare date strings correctly, the most significant field must come first, i.e., you must use the format `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Answer (score 1):

Set this date into date object and use `before(obj)` and `after(obj)` method of date object to compare two date.